# Update ticket priority not working in osticket

Tags: osticket

I am working in osticket version 1.10.0

I have created on custom module to update ticket priority.

I have update below tables in database of osticket priority update

```
1)ost_ticket for updated date , ip address ,last updated date
2)ost_ticket__cdata for priority field
3)ost_thread_event for update event of ticket
```

but still priority is not updated

Please anyone can tell me what thing is missing to update ticket priority in a custom way.

If I am updating it by edit ticket it is working fine but in custom way not working.

Answer (score 0):

I got answer to my above question there are two more tables that need to update for ticket update form

that tables are below,

```
1) ost_form_entry
2) ost_form_entry_values
```